# I want to post some questions that will require (finite, community wiki) list answers. Kosher?

Tags: discussion, policy, list-questions

Basically, while there is a sort of search system on d20PFSRD, I still find certain categories of feats very hard to locate when I need them.  I would like to make a few questions asking for lists of feats that meet specific broad themes, and go ahead and put the results of my research into a CW answer that can then be edited, added to, and curated as more content is released.

But I know list answers (and questions that need them) are usually frowned on.  I think these questions and their answers would be of significant use to a reasonably large subset of the community.  For a few examples of things I've wished I could call up a list of:

"What feats improve _____?"

- Ranged attacks
- Channel energy
- Companion creatures
- [Insert specific lore-recommended build, such as a sling-user or sword-and-pistol user]

To make the lists finite and useful to everyone, I would ask for official sources only, without any third-party or homebrew material.  Would these questions pass muster on RPG.SE?

Answer (score 14):

This is *probably* OK. A constrained list of a very particular type of information which is not likely to change often isn't going to cause the kind of practical problems as asking for an unbounded list. Making the answer CW mitigates one possible issue even more, by allowing the infrequent additions to be put right into the canonical answer instead of spurring drive-by "oh and one more" answers.

Unless some detail of execution causes problems, it should be fine. Worst case is that we learn the hard way and clean it up, which is not bad.

Comment: +1, but I think it's worth pointing out that "feats that improve ranged attacks" is probably too broad.

Comment: @Miniman is it, though?  Ranged attacks specifically, not including every Weapon Focus, Weapon Specialization, etc.  There aren't that many and they're spread between all the books.  It's an all-day job for me to find enough to fill up a 20-level build, that's why I had this idea in the first place.

Comment: Whether it is or isn't, the best way to find out is to post and see if it stays open or gets held as too broad.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I shall, then.  When I have some time this week I'll put my lists together and organize them, then I'll post the questions and my starts to the answers.

Comment: The first question, regarding shield use, is up.  I've decided to wait until these questions re-occur to me organically, per the guideline to post real problems, not theoreticals, before posting them myself.  This should help me space them out rather than flooding the place with lots of similar questions and potentially provoking spite-downvotes.  For the ranged weapon question, if I come up with enough feats, I'm thinking of splitting it - one for generic "all-ranged-attack" feats (that don't specify which type of ranged weapon) and a few for specific weapon types (bow/x-bow/thrown/firearm).

Comment: Organically is a great approach.

Comment: @gatherer818 3 hours in, this looks like a perfectly reasonable question and answer.