# Is this question about invisibility a list question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, list-questions

It turned out that there are multiple 1st-level abilities that make their user invisible, and that's why [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165276/30214) has 3 answers as of now, all of them showing a way to get invisibility at level 1.

I believe that more of them can potentially appear in the future.

Should this question hence be closed as a list question because of all the answers being equally correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not a list question, because it does not ask for a list.

The question asks what is the earliest level where invisibility is possible.  It asks for a minimum quantity, which can be measured and explained.  There may be multiple explanations (because there are multiple methods for invisibility) but it only needs one for a sufficient answer.

If it asked for all possible methods for gaining invisibility, then that would be a list question.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that your example list question doesn't quite match the definition of "list question" as used around SE. Specifically, it asks for a bounded set fulfilling a certain criteria (we maybe need a name for this question type... compilation question, maybe?) which is on topic (and we have several questions like this). The problematic, to-be-closed type, is asking for an unbounded list with no quality-criteria for answers (eg. "What is everyone's favourite way to gain invisibility?". We have meta on this, [starting here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil yeah, "list question" is an unfortunate term of art, IMO. "Good list question" and "bad list question" are the only straightforward alternatives I can think of that might catch on, and I'm not sure they're really any good =\

Comment: "List question" isn't actually a question that asks for a list. Nowadays it's basically a misnomer; it was already becoming inaccurate a decade ago. Instead it's shorthand for our questions not to ask criteria, nowadays defined in much better terms, one of which is the criteria that the answers will be an undifferentiated list of responses with none better or worse—that's the eponymous "list". Shog9 explains here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124489/152515