# Should I ask a question about listing content from Mike Mearls' Happy Fun Hour?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic, dnd-5e

I recently asked a question [Has there been a Kraken patron for the Warlock class in Unearthed Arcana?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157399/35259), the answer to which was that this Kraken warlock patron wasn't UA, but was rather part of Mike Mearls' Happy Fun Hour (HFH).

I like to keep up to date with the new UA class archetypes that come out, and after what I believe was the first class archetype to come out of HFH, the Order Domain, was then reproduced in a UA article (then released officially in GGtR, but that's besides the point here), I then stopped paying attention to HFH, assuming any new archetypes would similarly appear in UA (since videos are more awkward to watch at work when I only have so long at lunch, and glancing over a pdf is much quicker and easier).

Clearly I was mistaken in this. I'm now wondering what other class archetypes have been created in HRH that I am not aware of. I want to ask a question like **"What are all the class archetypes Mike Mearls has made in HFH?"** (which I'm guessing might be a list question, and one that will require updating if/when he creates more; unless HFH eventually stopped running, then maybe this problem would be mitigated), or perhaps **"Is there a (legal) website somewhere that keeps track of new class archtypes created in HFH?"** (which is probably a shopping question).

Is there an on-topic variation of this question, or is RPG.SE simply not the place to ask such a thing?

Comment: Whilst linksassin's answer correctly states that the second question I pose would be an off-topic shopping question, it seems as though such a list does exist after all (and it was from the same site as the link that V2Blast used on the linked question), so I'll just post it here, since I doubt I'll bother asking a question now I've found this: [https://thinkdm.org/hfh/](https://thinkdm.org/hfh/)

Comment: Are you sure that the existence of the Kraken patron disproves you hypothesis? Isn't the Lurker in the Deep patron in some way an evolution of the Kraken patron idea, so it's subsequent appearance in UA actually supports your premise that you don't need to keep up with HFH?

Comment: @Tiggerous This thought has occurred to me; looking at the archetypes in that link from my comment above, it seems as though it's very much in a development stage before that which is presented in UA, so I'm tempted to keep ignoring HFH after all and assume that anything that gets developed _enough_ will then make it into UA. The Lurker in the Deep could well be what happened to the Kraken patron, as you mentioned; developed further then released as UA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Your first question is probably fine

[Bounded List questions are on-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9465/48759) and this question would by definition be bounded. It's probably not a great question and I don't know how popular it would be with vote (I expect at least a few downvotes) but it shouldn't get closed.

The version of the question that asks for a website is definitely a shopping question and would be closed. If such a site exists it should come up in an answer to the first version of the question. Ask about the problem, not your solution to the problem.

I think you have done a good job of making this a clear and answerable question based on this meta. So long as you go with the first version of the question I don't foresee any major issues.

Comment: To add/sidenote: The answer to the first question would be bounded at any one point in time, but would need updating every week( assuming it resumes?) and as such would be a great use of a community wiki answer.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Answers could certainly choose to use a community wiki. However, if they do or not makes no difference to the communities ability to keep it updated. Consider the similar cause of [Nitsua60's official sources answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84837/48759)

Comment: @linksassin I'm not sure if the "official rules" post ever went CW and back. I wonder if you're thinking of the "all the races" post, which definitely cycled CW and back.

Comment: @nitsua60 I meant that as an example that is doesn't need to be community wiki to be an update-able list. But yes perhaps the [races post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77248/48759) is a better example.

Comment: @linksassin aaah, gotcha. Either way: six (authors) of one, a half-dozen (editors) of the other =)